# Converting multiple categorical columns to binary (0/1) in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to know how to convert multiple columns in a dataframe containing 'yes/no' to '1/0'.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WymlC.png)

I did it using the replace function, but this was two lines of code, and this can be tedious job if there are multiple such columns.
If I try

```
final_df['ads','premium'].replace({'yes':1,'no':0})
```

it gives me an error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPlJN.png)

Comment: *it gives me an error* what error is it? Please add what it says about said error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace in several columns at once using this syntax:

```
df[['B', 'C']] = df[['B', 'C']].replace({'yes': 1, 'no': 0})
```

(Edit:) With more columns:

```
list_of_columns = ['a','b','c','d','e']
df[list_of_columns] = df[list_of_columns].replace({'yes': 1, 'no': 0})
```

Comment: Thanks this works! 
But say there were 5 columns what should I do then?

Comment: No problem! You can have a list of any numbers of columns.  Edited to reflect.